# How to setup a custom url with custom domain for a specific action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, namespaces

For a bike rental management app, I set up an embedded javascript script form, bike rental companies can implement on their websites to let users search through their bike inventory for specific dates. Once clicked, they arrive on my website where they can finish the booking.

**Goal**
For these booking pages on my app, I would like to create an url format in the form of:

```
https://booking.{@shop.website}/action
```

**Attempts**
I tried changing the host for the respective controller action, via 2 two attempt

**attempt 1** Using `set_booking_namespace`, still resulting in  getting the host of my app in the url.

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  #create a new shop
  before_action :set_booking_namespace, only: [:shop_availability]

  def shop_availability
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    authorize @shop
  end

  def set_booking_namespace
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: @shop.website}
  end
end
```

==> resulting url: `http://localhost:3000/shops/66/shop_availability`

**Attempt 2** Redirecting to subdomain and host in controller action. This gave me the desired url, but resulted in the error message that the IP address cannot be found.

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController

  def shop_availability
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    authorize @shop
    redirect_to  subdomain: 'booking', :controller => 'shops', :action => "shop_availability", host: @shop.website
  end
```

==> resulting error message: `booking.bikeshop.nl’s server IP address could not be found.`

Comment: you can something like
redirect_to subdomain: 'booking', :controller => 'shops', :action => "set_booking_namespace"

Comment: Thanks. Following your tip, I tried ```redirect_to  subdomain: 'booking', :controller => 'shops', :action => "shop_availability", host: @shop.website```. This indeed gave me the desired url, but resulted in the error message ```booking.bikeshop.nl’s server IP address could not be found.```

Comment: on local it will work like booking.lvh.me:3000